# How to check if something exist, then create and save it inside an array

Tags: python

I'm running a script to get information from an URL and then create a Json file. With that, I'll read thought the info, save the ones that I need and then insert into the database.
But, I'm having problem with a part of this info.

**Info from the URL, saved in JSON**

```
"images": [
        {
            "type": "PosterPortrait", 
            "url": "https://ingresso-a.akamaihd.net/img/cinema/cartaz/22455-cartaz.jpg"
        }, 
        {
            "type": "PosterHorizontal", 
            "url": "https://ingresso-a.akamaihd.net/img/cinema/cartaz/22455-destaque.jpg"
        }
    ], 
    "trailers": []
```

This is the part and with that I have to:

- Check if there is something inside trailers
- Save it in a array, regarding for their "type" and "url"
- Save them in my database

I made a code to do that, the problem is, I'm new to python and I don't think it's working quiet right.

**insert-events.py**

```
if(i['trailers'][0]):
        a = array.arr(
            array.arr('url' = i['images'][0]['url'], 'type' = i['images'][0]['type']),
            array.arr('url' = i['images'][1]['url'], 'type' = i['images'][1]['type']),
            array.arr('url' = i['trailers'][0]['url'], 'type' = Trailer),
            array.arr('url' = i['trailers'][1]['url'], 'type' = Trailer),
        )
    else:
        a = array.arr(
            array.arr('url' = i['images'][0]['url'], 'type' = i['images'][0]['type']),
            array.arr('url' = i['images'][1]['url'], 'type' = i['images'][1]['type']),
        )
```

This is the part of the code to get the info from the JSON and, then, save it in as an array of arrays.

**Error**

```
File "insert-events.py", line 46
array.arr('url' = i['images'][0]['url'], 'type' = i['images'][0]['type']),
SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression
```

So, what I'm doing it wrong? It's the array structure or when I try to save the info?
Any help would be appreciate. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you are seeing is because it looks like you are trying to call a function/class with keyword arguments, but not using the keywords, instead using the string.

```
def foo(a, b):
    pass

foo(a=1, b=2) # Correct
foo('a'=1, 'b'=2) # Incorrect
```

---

If you want to save stuff with key/value associations, I would recommend using a [`dict`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp) (or maybe a [`list`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists.asp) of `dict`s in your case)

```
if(i['trailers'][0]):
    a = [
        {'url': i['images'][0]['url'], 'type': i['images'][0]['type']},
        {'url': i['images'][1]['url'], 'type': i['images'][1]['type']},
        ] # etc.
else:
    a = [
        {'url': i['images'][0]['url'], 'type': i['images'][0]['type']},
        {'url': i['images'][1]['url'], 'type': i['images'][1]['type']},
        ]
```

---

Lastly as a semi-unrelated note, checking for `i['trailers'][0]` will throw an `IndexError` if `i['trailers']` is an empty list (`[]`). You can check for something in `i['trailers']` using just `if i['trailers']:`.